# Colouring an Excel stacked bar chart's points in relation to a value assigned in a table

Tags: excel, charts, excel-2010, vba

I am trying to create a roadmap/timeline in Excel 2010 using a stacked bar chart. I have provided a link below to an image which should explain my intentions with the chart. I wish to present different events in the chart and they should be drawn in relation to their duration. The longer the event is, the longer its respective bar is.

I have managed to build a macro that creates a chart of my liking. However, I wish to add another functionality to it. As it can be seen from the picture below, there is a column called 'Type' in the original table. It stands for the status of the event, whether it is completed, canceled or being planned. My aim is to have the chart represent this data by coloring the bars either red (if canceled), green(if completed) or blue (if planned) depending on what value the particular event in question has in its Type row.

Below is the code behind the macro that the button 'Create a New Event View' uses. I would like to know how to implement the coloring, preferably in this very same macro so that the user only needs to click the button.

```
Sub CreateEventTable()

Dim timespan_start As Date
Dim timespan_end As Date
timespan_start = Application.InputBox("Type start date:")
timespan_end = Application.InputBox("Type end date:")

ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart(xlBarStacked, Range("E2").Left, Range("E2").Top).Select

With ActiveChart
  .SetSourceData Source:=Range("$A$1:$B$12, $D$1:$D$12"), PlotBy:=xlColumns
  .SeriesCollection(1).Values = Range("B2:B12")
  .SeriesCollection(1).XValues = Range("A2:A12")
  .SetElement msoElementLegendNone
  .ChartGroups(1).GapWidth = 31
  .SeriesCollection(2).ApplyDataLabels
  .SeriesCollection(2).DataLabels.ShowCategoryName = True
  .SeriesCollection(2).DataLabels.ShowValue = False
  .SeriesCollection(1).Format.Fill.Visible = msoFalse
  .Axes(xlValue).MinimumScale = timespan_start
  .Axes(xlValue).MaximumScale = timespan_end

End With
End Sub
```

Here is the link to the image which hopefully explains the overall structure:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/gTmZ8.jpg

I appreciate your invaluable help! I am happy to provide more details if deemed necessary.

Comment: You could have a look at the [Peltier Tech Blog](http://peltiertech.com/WordPress/conditional-formatting-of-excel-charts/) for a very elegant solution.

Answer (score 0):

Best solution here is not VBA. You'll need to create multiple series for your chart, have them overlapped, and use formulas to populate if they meet the criteria. Changes automatically, and very easy to maintain.

As Skip Intro said, Jon Peltier is the chart master.

This link will get you started in the right direction.

http://peltiertech.com/WordPress/conditional-formatting-of-excel-charts/